# Are structs in .NET meant to be a collection of constants?

Tags: .net, struct, constants, immutability

All over you will read that structs are meant to be immutable/keep values that do not change.

I wonder why I have not seen a much simpler and concise definition:
If you have multiple constant values and you can group them into one meaningful unit/under a single meaningful name (and/or want to add/attach some behavior) - that's when you use a struct - nothing more than a collection of constants, possibly with methods "attached".

Actually reflecting on what I wrote above - the only real reason to define a struct is if I DO HAVE behavior that should be "attached" to them. Otherwise, I would do pretty well simply declaring a public static class, and all of my constants there.

Example:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static string C1 = "c1";
    public static string C2 = "c2";
    public static string C3 = "c3";
}
```

the same, using a struct

```
public struct Constants
{
    public string C1 = "c1";
    public string C1 = "c2";
    public string C1 = "c3";
}
```

If I need no behavior to be done on these constant values, using constants seem to be the proper solution, since using structs I would be making copies of the same values, needlessly.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

In .NET languages, a struct is fundamentally an aggregation of variables rather than an object.  A struct which doesn't allow members to be modified except by struct assignment (replacement), which copies *all* members of one struct to another, will behave similarly to an object; one which allows members to be modified in any other way will not.  Some people promote the a simplified view that "everything in .NET is an object", even though such a view is inconsistent with the way that .NET actually works; types that do not behave like objects go against that philosophy.

In reality, there are two good uses for structs.  The usage which "everything is an object" people like it to employ structs in cases where immutable objects might be semantically ideal, but inefficient.  Structs which allow no modification except replacement offer essentially equivalent behavior, but may offer much better performance if certain conditions are met.  The MSDN guidelines do a pretty good idea of explaining what conditions a data type should meet in order for an "object-style" struct to be the best representation.

Another usage which is no less valid, though it contradicts the "everything is an object" philosophy, is to use a struct (i.e. an aggregation of variables) *as* an aggregation of independent but related variables.  Something like a graphical block-copy operation, in addition to needing source- and destination drawing contexts and a copy mode, also needs to have the source X, Y, Width, and Height, and destination X, Y, Width, and Height.  That's eleven parameters.  Grouping together the two groups of (X, Y, Width, Height) into type `Rectangle` reduces the parameter count to a much more reasonable five.  Passing a `Rectangle` is equivalent--from both a semantic and performance standpoint--to passing four separate variables, and should be thought of in such terms.  Some people find it "surprising" that a method like:

```
void Foo(Rectangle r) { r.X += 23; }
```

doesn't modify the passed-in rectangle, but if one were to rewrite the method as the semantically-equivalent:

```
void Foo(int r_X, int r_Y, int r_Width, int r_Height) { r_X += 23; }
```

it would be obvious that it only modifies the passed-in copy of r_X.

If one wants to have a type which represents a "shareable" rectangle, such that multiple items can attach to it, and a change to that rectangle will be visible to all those items, then it should be a class.  If, however, one wishes to have a type which can hold its bounds as an aggregation of variables which are independent from anything else in the universe but which can be conveniently worked with independently but also passed as a group, then a struct which simply exposes fields `X`, `Y`, `Width`, and `Height` would be ideal.  Such a struct wouldn't behave like an object, but that would hardly mean it wasn't useful.

Comment: When people say "everything is an object", they're using the concept of objects, not the `Object` type. Under this definition, structs of any behavior are indeed objects.

Comment: @CoryNelson: The "everything is an object" notion refers in significant measure to the fact that structure types derive from `System.ValueType` which in turn derives from `System.Object`.  Indeed, if one passes a struct to a method which expects a parameter of type `Object`, that method will receive a reference to a heap instance whose type derives from `System.Object` and behaves like it.  Every structure type definition, however, actually defines two kinds of things: a heap object type which behaves like a derivative of `Object`, and a storage-location type which does not.

Comment: The magic of deriving value types from a reference type is indeed an odd MacGyvering. I'm merely commenting on your somewhat venemous notion of the "everything is an object people" which probably doesn't belong in an answer.

Comment: @CoryNelson: A field of type `Rectangle` holds four integer values.  Nothing less; nothing more.  If class `MyThing` holds a field of type `Rectangle`, that field definition will allocate space for four integer values; the fact that that those locations should be regarded as a `Rectangle` will not be implied by anything stored in them, but rather will be part of the definition of `MyThing`.  By contrast, if one stores a `Rectangle` into a variable of type `Object`, the fact that the thing to which that variable refers should be regarded as a `Rectangle` will be stored with the object itself.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Perhaps you would suggest some term other than "fictional"? All .NET languages compile to a language called CLI, which has its own specification. That spec states that each value-type definition creates both a storage-location type and a heap object type. To the extent that the CLI spec and observable behavior match, I would regard the CLI spec as "truth" and any contrary claims "fiction". Would you prefer "inaccurate"?